# ObjectDataSource and overloaded functions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

e.g. say I have an ObjectDataSource in an aspx page defined like this :

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsList" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData"  
TypeName="Company.DataFetcher"  .... >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="p1" Type="Object" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="p2" Type="Object" />        
    </SelectParameters> </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The DataFetcher.GetData method might have a signature like this :

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public DSData GetData(int p1, int p2)
```

All works fine. Now, if I define an overload of the GetData function with extra parameters. e.g. :

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public DSData GetData(int p1, int p2, int p3)
```

might this cause any problems ? I'm thinking ASP.NET will be smart enough to call the correct SelectMethod based on the parameters passed, but is there anything to look out for ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ASP.net will do this. Because even in sql datasource the procedure name is Unique for a Database and Method binding is done same for both. I am not sure though, better check it out yourself.

Have a look at this to see How a Data Source Control Creates Parameters for Data-bound Fields (Including Object datasource)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228051.aspx

and here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hkzhy5.aspx